# FIRApp.configure() is crashing my ios xcode swift app (firebase)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

From firebase, I originally had just installed the pods

pod 'Firebase/Core' and pod 'Firebase/Database'

And then I put FIRApp.configure() in

`func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {`

in AppDelegate. It worked fine.

However, I wanted to also add many of the other pods, so just now, I added pod 'Firebase/Messaging', pod 'Firebase/Invites', pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks', pod 'Firebase/Crash', pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', pod 'Firebase/Auth', and pod 'Firebase/Storage' into the podfile and installed the pods using terminal, which worked fine. However, now when I run my .xcworkspace file again it crashes with "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException". Did I set up the pods wrong or something? Maybe I have to delete that .xcworkspace file and then redo installation so that it creates a new one?

Comment: You may want to show what does your podfile looks like, and also show exactly what type of error message you get in the console.

Comment: place `FIRApp.configure()` inside `override init() { super.init() }` block of your AppDelegate It's not your podfile.

Comment: There's probably another line or two right after "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" that's telling you what the exact exception is. Can you look for that and share it on here? That'll give you a pretty good idea of what's wrong...

Answer (score -2):

Try to remove all pods from podfile, then save, and reinstall pods > pod install, it should remove all of them, open again xcworkspace and see what gonna happen then, if its ok install firebase pods again (first put them in podfile). And btw. have you added googleservice-project.plist and set everything right on firebase site?